# Why does WebAssembly fail to build on fresh Uno Platform template

Tags: .net-core, ubuntu-20.04, uno-platform

### Summary:

When I attempt to build and run my Uno WebAssembly on Ubuntu 20.04, it fails. The error cites a file or directory that doesn't exist.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Ubuntu 20.04 platform
2. Install .NET Core SDK 3.1.403
3. Follow the "Getting Started on VSCode" tutorial [here](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/get-started-vscode.html)
4. When you attempt to start the app with the .NET Core Launch configuration, note that the build fails.

### Error Details:

```
/home/<user>/.nuget/packages/uno.wasm.bootstrap/1.3.4/build/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.targets(126,2): error : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory [/home/<user>/Projects/uapp/uapp.Wasm/uapp.Wasm.csproj]
```

### What I've tried

My knowledge of Uno Platform is approximately 1 day old. I'm not sure I understand enough about it to even know what to try, but I have done these things:

- Run `dotnet run` from within the `uapp.Skia.Gtk`, which successfully opened the window I expected to see.
- Run `dotnet run` from within `uapp.Wasm`, which resulted in the error described above.
- Look on the documentation for clues on why the file might not be found on a fresh template that's not been modified (I could not find anything)

### Question:

What should I be doing differently to get the Web Assembly to build and display the app correctly?

#### EDIT: The file in the error does exist, precisely in the path in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting [an error that may happen](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/issues/281) when building with some native components, like SQLite or Skia.

To fix this, you'll need to execute the [dotnet-setup.sh installation script](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/blob/51de348b63b91553bad34ef5598620420b222979/src/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/build/scripts/dotnet-setup.sh) which is not yet run automatically.

This script installs .NET Core, mono and ninja, on ubuntu-alike systems.